# Missing prefilled checkbox values from my array (mysql/PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox, mysqli

I'm pulling data where I have a column (in my current test) with 3 rows of data. My goal is to pre-fill the chekboxes of my form if the user selected industries before. Currently, it only checks the first result but doesn't show the other 2. I tried using a while loop but in those cases the form shows all the checkboxes 3 times if there is there is 3 rows in my data. I've tried multiple things but nothing works and I'm sure it is a simple fix but can't quite see it.

When I do the mysql command directly into the DB is gives me these results (for this example):

**industry_idindustry**

- 5
- 6
- 7

Can you help me?

PHP code:

```
    // Create connection and pull the data from 
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'profile') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$query = "SELECT industry_idindustry FROM `industry_has_member` WHERE member_idmember = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

echo '<tr><td width="30%">Industries: </td><td>';

$array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
array_push($array, $row['industry_idindustry']);
}

?>

<input type="checkbox" name="industries[]" value="1" <?php if(in_array('1',$array)){echo ' checked="checked"';}?>>None</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="industries[]" value="2" <?php if(in_array('2',$array)){echo ' checked="checked"';}?>>Film</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="industries[]" value="3" <?php if(in_array('3',$array)){echo ' checked="checked"';}?>>Television</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="industries[]" value="4" <?php if(in_array('4',$array)){echo ' checked="checked"';}?>>Music</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="industries[]" value="5" <?php if(in_array('5',$array)){echo ' checked="checked"';}?>>Gaming</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="industries[]" value="6" <?php if(in_array('6',$array)){echo ' checked="checked"';}?> >Books</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="industries[]" value="7" <?php if(in_array('7',$array)){echo ' checked="checked"';}?> >Comic Books</br>
```

Comment: now change your password

Comment: Programming is more complex than product management. For instance, one cannot go without checking their prerequisites. Say, a product manager can assume that $array contains all the required values, and keep running project with no problem. Programming is another matter. You have to actually know, what $array is and what data it contains.

Comment: @Strawberry come on, who needs a localhost password from a developers PC for a test database?

Comment: Can you guys suggest some code to help me understand what I'm missing? I've look at several Q&As on stackexchange plus books and tried several things.

Comment: all you need is to look at the manual page for the mysqli_fetch_array function, to make yourself aware of what does this function actually do, what does it return and how to use it to get the desired data

Comment: I did read this as well, but having worked on it for so long everything I tried wasn't working. I even did the loop suggested below but included the form inside the brackets so the reason why it didn't work. So y'all thanks for the clarification. I edited my code above to reflect the changes.

Comment: And again you tried to use your project management habits which never work for programming. In programming you cannot "try" just random actions in hope that one of them accidentally worked. You should *understand* what are you doing first, then choose the proper action and keep with it.

Comment: Don't worry in any cases where this is true I go back to the code and re-read to understand what's happening otherwise I'm not learning. My goal is to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to get an array of `industry_idindustry` values:

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
  array_push($array, $row['industry_idindustry']);
}
```

Comment: I actually did this one but the input/form was inside the brackets, so thank you thank you thank you. I was going mad.